# Which are the ways we can display the content of a collection beyond h:dataTable or rich:dataGrid?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I wish to write the content of a list, but not the "table way".

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{pessoaAction.pessoas}" var="pessoaItem">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{pessoaItem.nome}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

And

```html
<rich:dataGrid value="#{pessoaAction.pessoas}" var="pessoa" columns="1">
    <h:outputText value="#{pessoa.nome}"></h:outputText>
</rich:dataGrid>
```

That solutions bring me what I want this way:

- Danielson
- Melissa
- Carlos

But I want to have them this way (inline)

- Danielson; Melissa; Carlos.

Some ideas?

Comment: Are you using JSF 1.2 and RichFaces 3.3 or JSF 2 and RichFaces 4?

Comment: You whould comment answers and/or accept them if they resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with simple JSF iteration component like this :

```
<ui:repeat value="#{pessoaAction.pessoas}" var="pessoa" varStatus="status">
    <h:outputText value="#{pessoa}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{status.last ? '.' : '; '}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Thanks for the "ui:repeat" with this if-statement. Sorry if my question was so poor!

Comment: @DanielsonAlvesJúnior No questions are too poor if they help someone. That's how we all learn from others!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the words, Alexandre !